# How do I redirect a specific permalink wordpress page to another in .htaccess?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have this .htaccess file as generated by Wordpress and an eCommerce plugin:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^.products/images/(\d+)/?\??(.*)$ /wp-content/plugins/shopp/core/image.php?siid=$1&$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I now have to redirect someone who visits http://mydomain.com/golf to http://mydomain.com/products/category/golf/

I have these rules in a block above the existing block which semi-work:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^golf.*$ products/category/golf/ [R=permanent,L]
RewriteRule ^cycling.*$ products/category/cycling/ [R=permanent,L]
#...etc
</IfModule>
```

The problem is, if someone types http://mydomain.com/golfshoes for example, it still redirects. I have tried to play about with the wildcards etc but cant get it to only allow /golf and /golf/

Also... is that the most efficient way of setting these rules up? I should I be doing some sort of if or if or if then redirect?

Thanks :)
Ben

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the 2 regular expressions to:

```
RewriteRule ^golf(/.*)?$ products/category/golf/$1 [R=permanent,L]
RewriteRule ^cycling(/.*)?$ products/category/cycling/$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

The **(/.*)** matches a "/" or "/something", and the **?** means that it may not be there. The **$1** at the target indicates whatever was matched in the parentheses. So someone going to http://mydomain.com/golf/foo.html will get served `/prodducts/category/golf/foo.html`

Comment: Perfect, thanks Jon. I want it to only allow 'golf' and 'golf/' and not 'golf/whatever' so I've changed it to: 
RewriteRule ^golf(/)?$ products/category/golf/ [R=permanent,L]